# Remove Header rows based on keyword using Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have searched around and I have seen solutions where to remove top 3 rows or something static. 
But I have a daily csv report files where the header rows are not always the same, for example. yesterday's file will have 4 rows of headers and today i have 7 rows of header.

But all of the data starts with one "real" header row. 
I think if I can find a way to do a search and match below name and then remove everything above that.

`"Statistics Date","Branch","Branch Name","Company ID"`

below is what I got so far. Basically read into that csv, find above text, remove anything above those texts and save it or append to a new file name.

```
$filedaily=C:\ftp\dailyfile.csv
$header="Statistics Date","Branch","Branch Name","Company ID"
Get-content $filedaily
```

Edit after Alex's solution:
after the output script. below is what I have found on the inconsistency of the output.

original text

```
"Amnet»Programatic»728x90»NA»BAN»DT»CPC»AUT»W»NA»TP»NA»AzureGlobal"
```

Output text with added character

```
"AmnetÂ»ProgramaticÂ»728x90Â»NAÂ»BANÂ»DTÂ»CPCÂ»AUTÂ»WÂ»NAÂ»TPÂ»NAÂ»AzureGlobal"
```

Comment: This is resolved by adding -Encoding UTF8 at the 3rd line of the script after $filedaily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression:

```
$filedaily = "C:\ftp\dailyfile.csv"
$outfile = "C:\ftp\outfile.csv"

$string = Get-Content -Path $filedaily | Out-String
$regex = '(?s).*("Statistics Date","Branch","Branch Name","Company ID".*)'

$string -replace $regex, '$1' | Out-File -FilePath $outfile
```

Comment: Hi I did what you have posted here. But the output file is bit different than the input file. one of the line in the output file added bunch of characters. see below
Original text 
"Amnet»Programatic»728x90»NA»BAN»DT»CPC»AUT»W»NA»TP»NA»AzureGlobal"

output text 
"AmnetÂ»ProgramaticÂ»728x90Â»NAÂ»BANÂ»DTÂ»CPCÂ»AUTÂ»WÂ»NAÂ»TPÂ»NAÂ»AzureGlobal"

Comment: Probably an encoding issue. What is the encoding of the original file? I would guess it's UTF-8. If so, add `-Encoding UTF8` to the Out-File command.

Comment: when I use notepad++ to open it. it says. UNIX UTF-8 w/o BOM

Comment: I also added -Encoding UTF8 between out-File and -FilePath. Ran it. still get that character